# Hybrid Federated Search incorrect in SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, hybrid-solution

We are experiencing an issue when we display our on premises SharePoint 2016 results in our SharePoint 365 instance. Our environment is as follows:

- On premises SharePoint 2016 (sp2016.internal.com) - indexing on-premises SharePoint 2010, on-premises SharePoint 2010, and asp.net website.
- SharePoint 365 (external.sharepoint.com) - indexing SharePoint 365. Users are reuired to be on the internal network for authenication to work.
- Revere Proxy (hybridseach.external.com)

SharePoint 365 is configured to consume the on-premises search results by the going through the reverse proxy. When on-premises SharePoint (sp2016.internal.com) results are displayed in SharePoint 365, the URLs show the URL of the reverse proxy (hybridseach.external.com ) and not the correct internal URL (sp2016.internal.com). Users clicking on search results are getting routed to an incorrect URL and are receiving certificate errors.

Is there a way to display the actual internal URLs when results are displayed in SharePoint 365?

Comment: "SharePoint 365 is configured to consume the on-premises search results by the going through the reverse proxy." -> Please describe how this was set up (Link to Blog or so is OK).

Comment: We used the Microsoft docs found here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/hybrid/configure-hybrid-federated-search-sharepoint-onlineroadmap